# Bootstrap 3 Menu does not work on BlackBerry 10 devices

Tags: blackberry, twitter-bootstrap-3, blackberry-10

I just converted a site to use the Twitter Bootstrap 3 framework, it works just great on all devices EXCEPT BlackBerry 10.

It even works on the BlackBerry 10 Simulator just fine.

The problem is that the navigation buttons for the mobile drop down do not work.

Has anyone come across this & have a fix? [and an explanation as to what is going on?]

**UPDATE**
Just got an answer in github [sort of] "Bootstrap 3 does not support BlackBerry devices"

Answer (score 1):

I've edited my previous post and erased it

bootstrap navigation menu works fine with the BlackBerry OS 10

you can check it on the bootstrap website, open it from your device

these are the three navigation menus types, I've tried all of them from my Q5

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-static-top/

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/

only with the fixed top, the last item at bottom is slightly out of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 3 does not support BlackBerry devices

Answer (score 0):

currently on BlackBerry OS 10 I'm experiencing that everything done with bootstrap 3 and jquery is displayed correctly.